# SDL2 compilation from source code is the same as sdl2-dev?

Tags: c, linux, sdl, parrot-os

I had issue installing sdl2 with apt then i installed it with the source code.

My question is, if I compiled from source code is it okay for development or do I need something else like sdl2-dev packages?

Comment: runtime package is just the library. dev package is just the header files. source gives you everything.

Comment: Building from source is enough, and it's even better than using the prepackaged one. SDL2 has some clever system to load available dependencies at runtime, which is disabled at least in the version in the Ubuntu repos. This helps to distribute your app to others.